# How to make new button links webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

/* poor at English, sorry */

I'm trying to make New Tab customized to me.
this project contain modal, and this modal contains "making button to Web" function.
but after making button, appended button make problem.
this is my code.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("ID-modal");
var btnn = document.getElementsByClassName("goto-item")[0];
var span = document.getElementById("modal-cancel");
const modal_complete = document.getElementById("modal-complete");
var goto_content = document.querySelector(".goto-content");
const DEFAULT = "";

btnn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

function addBtn() {
  var text_1 = document.getElementById("modal-text1").value;
  var text_2 = document.getElementById("modal-text2").value;
  if (text_1 == "" || text_2 == "") {
    btn_off();
  } else {
    modal_complete.setAttribute('disabled', 'false');
    var newBtn = document.createElement("input");
    newBtn.type = "button";
    newBtn.value = text_1;
    goto_content.appendChild(newBtn);
    newBtn.setAttribute("onclick", goWeb(text_2));
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function goWeb(text_2) {
  location.href = text_2;
}
```

```html
<div class="goto">
  <div class="goto-contain">
    <div class="goto-content">

    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Add" class="goto-item" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="ID-modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p id="modal-baro">바로가기 추가</p>
    <h7 class="modal-text3">이름</h7><br>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="modal-text1"><br><br><br>
    <h7 class="modal-text3">URL</h7><br>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="modal-text2"><br><br><br>
    <span class="modal-span" id="modal-delete">삭제</span>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
    <span class="modal-span" id="modal-cancel">취소</span>&emsp;
    <span class="modal-span" id="modal-complete" onclick="addBtn();">완료</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

cause I have no idea of where is the problem area,
sorry about poor mess codes.

Is there problem at goWeb or newBtn.setAttribute ?

Comment: text_2 means 'go-to-webpage link' string.

Comment: I recommend you put your code on https://jsfiddle.net and share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `setAttribute` you will need to pass a string:

```
newBtn.setAttribute("onclick", 'goWeb("' + text_2 + '")');
```

But instead I would just use the `[onclick][1]` method which is made for this and works across all browsers:

```
newBtn.onclick = function() {
  goWeb(text_2)
}
```

We wrap the function inside an anonymous function to prevent it being triggered immediately.